# Gibt es eigentlich das Wort »praktizieren« in der deutschen Sprache? Wenn ja: Wie oft wird es benutzt?

Tags: word-usage

Vor ein paar Tagen sprach ich mit einer Koreanerin, die in Deutschland lebt und ziemlich gutes Deutsch spricht. Aber da sagte ich irgendwas wie, dass ich noch »viel Deutsch *praktizieren«* müsse, um gute Kontrolle der Sprache zu bekommen. Ihrer Antwort war irgendwas wie: »Nein, du musst das Wort *üben* benutzen, weil es das Wort *praktizieren* nicht gibt.«

Sofort sagte ich nichts, aber später ist mir eingefallen, dass ich dieses Wort bereits irgendwo gehört habe. Zusätzlich gibt es dieses Wort auch in Onlinewörterbüchern im Internet. Also gibt es dieses Wort im Hochdeutsch oder nicht?

Comment: Man kann durchaus auch seine Religion *praktizieren*, also *praktizierender Christ* sein.

Comment: @tofro Man es ist sehr komisch, weil ich gedacht habe: "Kann man dieses Wort für eine Religion nutzen". Dann in zwei oder drei Sekunden kommt Ihrer Antwort. 
Dankeschön,

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Das Wort *praktizieren* gibt es im Deutschen, aber es ist kein Synonym für das Wort *üben*.

Die häufigste Bedeutung ist »ausüben« oder »arbeiten«:

> Dr. Klein praktiziert erst seit einem Jahr als Zahnarzt.

Das bedeutet:

> Dr. Klein arbeitet erst seit einem Jahr als Zahnarzt.

Eine andere Bedeutung: ein Praktikum machen

> Maria praktiziert beim Wochenblatt.

Das bedeutet:

> Maria macht beim Wochenblatt ein Praktikum.

---

Falls du bei »praktizieren« an das englische Verb »to practice« denkst: Diese beiden Wörter sind falsche Freunde (false friends).

Comment: Die Bedeutung *Praktikum machen* halte ich für möglich, aber in Deutschland für ungebräuchlich. Durch die Existenz der ebenfalls angegebenen Bedeutung *arbeiten* wird der Satz mehrdeutig, sodass Präzisierung notwendig werden kann. *Praktikum machen* ist dagegen eindeutig und kaum länger.

Comment: Ein Praktikum beim Wochenblatt und die Tätigkeit eines langjährig studierten Arztes sind ja nun doch zwei sehr verschiedene Tätigkeiten. Praktizieren für ein Praktikum machen scheint mir sehr ungebräuchlich und auch irreführend.

Answer (score 4):

Es gibt das Wort **praktizieren** im Deutschen, allerdings bedeutet es nicht *üben*, sondern **ausüben**. Besonders Ärzte *praktizieren* ihren Beruf in ihrer *Praxis*.

> Sie praktiziert als Kinderärztin. Ihre Praxis liegt direkt gegenüber der Schule.

Außerdem gibt es noch die übertragene Bedeutung **etwas in unverständlicher Weise tun**:

> Er hatte es irgendwie hineinpraktiziert.

Answer (score 4):

Ja. Zusätzlich zu den von Janka genannten Bedeutungen wird *praktizieren* für erlernte Fähigkeiten, wie etwa eine Fremdsprache oder ein Musikinstrument zu spielen, verwendet, allerdings meist in negierter Form.

> Ich habe Französisch in der Schule gelernt, aber nie praktiziert.

In diesem Zusammenhang bedeutet es soviel wie *praktisch anwenden*.  [DWDS](https://www.dwds.de/wb/praktizieren) nennt diese Bedeutung sogar an erster Stelle und weist ingesamt eine mittlere Häufigkeit aus.